# ¿Porque no se ejecuta evento onclick desde modal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap

Tengo la siguiente ventana modal, pero al dar clic en el button no se ejecuta el evento en c#, ni siquiera entra al método.
Aquí mi código:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalC" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title m-0 font-weight-bold text-danger" id="exampleModalLabel1">Titulo</h5>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<h6 style="float: left; width: 100%" class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">¿Esta seguro de eliminar la informacion?</h6>
<h6 style="float: left; width: 100%" class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-secondary">Justifique</h6>
<asp:TextBox ID="Just_c" runat="server" CssClass="fin_sC form-control" AutoComplete="off" Style="border-color: dodgerblue; text-transform: uppercase;" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="2" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="Just_c" ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{20,}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Se requieren al menos 20 caracteres" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="finS"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-secondary shadow-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
<asp:Button ID="Send_C" runat="server" Text="Aceptar" CssClass="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="finS" OnClick="SendC_Click" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```html
protected void SendC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Intenta eliminar esa linea y vuelve a escribir a lo mejor se perdió la propiedad.

Comment: Hola, cual linea? @OrlandoAguilera

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Send_C" runat="server" Text="Aceptar" CssClass="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm" causesvalidation="true" ValidationGroup="finS" OnClick="SendC_Click" />

Comment: Ya, pero sigue sin funcionar :c @OrlandoAguilera